# How can I force dropping intercept or equivalent in this linear model?

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, lm, anova

Consider the following table :

```
DB <- data.frame(
  Y =rnorm(6),
  X1=c(T, T, F, T, F, F),
  X2=c(T, F, T, F, T, T)
)
           Y    X1    X2
1  1.8376852  TRUE  TRUE
2 -2.1173739  TRUE FALSE
3  1.3054450 FALSE  TRUE
4 -0.3476706  TRUE FALSE
5  1.3219099 FALSE  TRUE
6  0.6781750 FALSE  TRUE
```

I'd like to explain my quantitative variable Y by two binary variables (TRUE or FALSE) without intercept.

The argument of this choice is that, in my study, we can't observe `X1=FALSE` and `X2=FALSE` at the same time, so it doesn't make sense to have a mean, other than 0, for this level.

### With intercept

```
m1 <- lm(Y~X1+X2, data=DB)
summary(m1)

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept)  -1.9684     1.0590  -1.859   0.1600  
X1TRUE        0.7358     0.9032   0.815   0.4749  
X2TRUE        3.0702     0.9579   3.205   0.0491 *
```

### Without intercept

```
m0 <- lm(Y~0+X1+X2, data=DB)
summary(m0)

Coefficients:
        Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
X1FALSE  -1.9684     1.0590  -1.859   0.1600  
X1TRUE   -1.2325     0.5531  -2.229   0.1122  
X2TRUE    3.0702     0.9579   3.205   0.0491 *
```

I can't explain why **two coefficients are estimated for the variable X1**. It seems to be equivalent to the intercept coefficient in the model with intercept.

### Same results

When we display the estimation for all the combinations of variables, the two models are the same.

```
DisplayLevel <- function(m){
  R <-  outer(
    unique(DB$X1),
    unique(DB$X2),
    function(a, b) predict(m,data.frame(X1=a, X2=b))
  )
  colnames(R) <- paste0('X2:', unique(DB$X2))
  rownames(R) <- paste0('X1:', unique(DB$X1))
  return(R)
}

DisplayLevel(m1)
          X2:TRUE  X2:FALSE
X1:TRUE  1.837685 -1.232522
X1:FALSE 1.101843 -1.968364

DisplayLevel(m0)
          X2:TRUE  X2:FALSE
X1:TRUE  1.837685 -1.232522
X1:FALSE 1.101843 -1.968364
```

So the two models are equivalent.

### Question

My question is : can we just estimate one coefficient for the first effect ? Can we force R to assign a 0 value to the combinations `X1=FALSE` and `X2=FALSE` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, we can, by

```
DB <- as.data.frame(data.matrix(DB))
## or you can do:
## DB$X1 <- as.integer(DB$X1)
## DB$X2 <- as.integer(DB$X2)

#            Y X1 X2
# 1 -0.5059575  1  1
# 2  1.3430388  1  0
# 3 -0.2145794  0  1
# 4 -0.1795565  1  0
# 5 -0.1001907  0  1
# 6  0.7126663  0  1

## a linear model without intercept
m0 <- lm(Y ~ 0 + X1 + X2, data = DB)

DisplayLevel(m0)
#             X2:1      X2:0
# X1:1  0.15967744 0.2489237
# X1:0 -0.08924625 0.0000000
```

I have explicitly coerced your `TRUE/FALSE` binary into numeric `1/0`, so that no contrast is handled by `lm()`.

The data appeared in my answer are different to yours, because you did not use `set.seed(?)` before `rnorm()` for reproducibility. But this is not a issue here.

Comment: Thanks you, your solution helps me a lot, but I've yet a misunderstanding.
When we use directly categorical variables as factors, R builds a design matrix (`?model.matrix`) with 0-1 values. We don't have to recode.
I don't understand why we have to use your clever trick, whereas R could automatically look after recoding. Is there an algebraic reason ?

Comment: Exactly and that is precisely what I don't understand : why R displays three columns ? Is it an R default ?

Comment: Ok it's that I thought. Thank you a lot. I'm a litte disappointed by R on this one...